# Sampling a normal distribution using Control.Monad.MonadRandom

Tags: haskell, distribution

I want to sample a Normal distribution with given mean and standard deviation. I know how to do that in various contexts like Data.Random.Rvar or Data.Random.MonadRandom.
However, the context of my function is Control.Monad.MonadRandom, and I would like to keep it that way as my whole project uses Control.Monad.MonadRandom.

Is there any way to do so, and could you help me do that?

Here is how the code looks like. Pattern is just an alias for Data.Vector Double and Weights is an alias for Data.Vector (Data.Vector Double) (ie a matrix)

```
train :: MonadRandom m => [Pattern] -> Int -> m Weights
train pats nr_hidden = do
  ws_start <- ws_start''
  foldM updateWS ws_start pats
    where ws_start'  = take p (repeat $ take nr_hidden $ repeat $ (normal 0.0 0.01))
         ws_start'' = vector2D <$> (sequence $ map sequence ws_start')
         p = length pats
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The quick answer

How to use a `Data.Random.RVar` inside a `Control.Monad.MonadRandom`?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Random as CMR
import Data.Random          as DR
import Data.Word (Word32)

gimmeRandom :: forall m . CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int
gimmeRandom = do
  r <- runRVar (uniform 0 100) (getRandom :: m Word32)
  return r
```

---

### Explanation

Effectively, you want to run a Monad inside a *formally different* Monad with similar semantics.

- `Data.Random.MonadRandom` and `Control.Monad.Random` are *formally* different because they are defined indepently in different places, and none is an instance of the other (there is no `instance DR.MonadRandom m => CMR.MonadRandom m` or the other way around).
- The Monads have similar semantics because they both provide random numbers from some randomness source, so it makes sense to expect that we can combine them somehow.

Let us say you have some code in a `Control.Monad.Random` interface:

```
import Control.Monad.Random as CMR

gimmeRandom :: CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int
gimmeRandom = do
  r <- getRandomR (0, 100)
  return r
```

We could run this like `evalRand gimmeRandom StdGen` which gives us an `Int`.

Now instead of `getRandomR`, you want to use one of the many available distributions provided by `Data.Random`.

For this example, we will try to replace `getRandomR (0, 100)` by `uniform 0 100 :: RVar Int`. How to we get the `Int` out of that `RVar Int` in our `CMR.MonadRandom` environment?

We want to run the `RVar` monad, for which we will probably have to provide a random number source, as the semantic suggests. We are looking for a monad-escaping function like [evalRand](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.8/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html#v%3aevalRand) for CMR. These escaping functions have type `m a -> someStuffNeededToRunTheMonad -> a`.

In the [docs about RVar](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/rvar/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-RVar.html#t%3aRVar), there is an example:

```
-- In a monad, using a RandomSource:
runRVar (uniform 1 100) DevRandom :: IO Int
```

Let's check `runRVar`:

```
runRVar :: RandomSource m s => RVar a -> s -> m a
```

Yes, that is a kind of escaping function: Given an `RVar` and a source for random numbers, it returns us the random result of the `RVar` inside our own monad `m`. This, however, requires, that there is an `instance RandomSource m s` that says that `s` is a randomness source for our monad `m`. Let's look for that instance.

What is our monad `m`? We want to run the `RVar` in `gimmeRandom`, so the monad is `CMR.MonadRandom m => m` (all monads that implement `CMR.MonadRandom`). What is the randomness source `s`? No clue yet. [Let us look in the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-source/0.3.0.2/doc/html/Data-Random-Source.html#t%3aRandomSource) which `RandomSource` instances exist:

```
RandomSource IO DevRandom
...
Monad m0 => RandomSource m0 (m0 Word32)
Monad m0 => RandomSource m0 (m0 Word64)
...
```

Aha! This says that *any* monad `m0` is an instance of `RandomSource` together with *a value coming from this monad* (e.g. `m0 Word32`). This hold of course also for our monad `CMR.MonadRandom`. We can also see that the `s`, `m0 Word32`, must be the random value generated by the randomness source.

What should we pass in as the `s` in `runRVar (uniform 0 100) s`? Something that generates random numbers in *our* monad, something of type `CMR.MonadRandom m => m Word32`. What is the `CMR` function to generate arbitrary things, e.g. some `Word32`? [getRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.8/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v%3agetRandom). So basically we want to write:

```
gimmeRandom :: CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int
gimmeRandom = do
  r <- runRVar (uniform 0 100) getRandom
  return r
```

Hmm, that does not compile:

```
Could not deduce (RandomSource m (m0 a0))
  arising from a use of `runRVar'
from the context (CMR.MonadRandom m)
  bound by the type signature for
             gimmeRandom :: CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int
```

`RandomSource m (m0 a0)`? That is weird, the `m` and the `m0` seem to be recognised as *different* monads by the compiler; we want them to be the same, as in `RandomSource m0 (m0 Word64)`.

Let us put the full signature into that place:

```
r <- runRVar (uniform 0 100) (getRandom :: CMR.MonadRandom m => m Word32)
```

Still the same error. This is because the `m` in that type signature, is really *any* monad implementing `CMR.MonadRandom`, not necessarily the `MonadRandom` in our `gimmeRandom` type signature.

(This is the same concept of shadowing as in lambda terms `(\x -> (\x -> f x))` where the inner `\x` is the one used in `f x`; or in first-order logic like `∀x . F(x) → ∀x . G(x)`, where the `x` in `G(x)` is the innermost defined one and need not be the same, not even of the same type, as the one in the outer `∀x`; or really in any other programming language with variable hiding/shadowing in inner scopes - just that here it is *type* variable shadowing).

So the only thing that we have to do is to tell the compiler that in the `getRandom` invocation, we don't want that to be for any `MonadRandom`, but for exactly that `MonadRandom m` that we have in the `gimmeRandom` type signature.

We can do that using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

[...]

gimmeRandom :: forall m . CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int
gimmeRandom = do
  r <- runRVar (uniform 0 100) (getRandom :: m Word32)
  return r
```

This makes that the `m` in `getRandom :: m ...` is to be chosen *exactly that* `CMR.MonadRandom m` from the top-level type signature.

This does compile and the problem is solved: We can use distributions from `Data.Random` in code using the `MonadRandom` interface. We could easily replace the `uniform` by another distribution.

**To summarise**, we have

- identified that we use two different monads from different packages but with same/overlapping semantics
- found out how to run/escape the monad we want to use inside our own (with `runRVar`)
- found out what to pass into the escaping function by looking at its typeclass restrictions and the instances provided for those
- written the right code (`runRVar (uniform 0 100) getRandom`)
- made it compile by saying which precise monad `getRandom` shall use.

---

If you are wondering why we chose `Word32` somewhat arbitrarily from the instances we can pick from, we just have to give the randomness source in *some* form, and *Word32* is one of the things `Data.Random` takes as input for generating other random stuff.

Comment: You can simplify to: `r <- runRVar (uniform 0 100) (getRandom :: m Word32)`

Comment: Why is "forall m" necessary in your solution? I thought it was implicit in haskell for any "unbounded type" (not sure about the proper vocabulary) in a function signature to be treated as if there were a "forall a" clause at the toplevel. But without it, I get back the error `Could not deduce (R.RandomSource m (m0 Word32))`.

Comment: @GuillaumeChérel That is so that you can use `m` again in `getRandom :: m Word32`. If you want to tell Haskell "I want this to be the same type `m` as in the function type signature, you have to write `forall m` into the type signature to make the `m` have scrope across the entire function body. If you don't write the `forall m`, then the `m` exists only within the local scope `CMR.MonadRandom m => m Int`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some sample code that (inefficiently) generates samples from the normal distribution with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`, using only functions from Control.Monad.Random.

```
import Control.Monad.Random

-- |Generates uniform random variables.
unif :: (MonadRandom m) => m Double
unif = getRandomR (0,1)

-- |Generate two samples from the standard normal distribution, using
--  the Box-Muller method.
stdNormals :: (MonadRandom m) => m (Double,Double)
stdNormals = do
    u <- unif
    v <- unif
    let r = sqrt((-2) * log u)
    let arg1 = cos (2 * pi * v)
    let arg2 = sin (2 * pi * v)
    return (r * arg1, r * arg2)

-- |Generate a single sample from the standard normal distribution, by
--  generating two samples and throwing away the second one.
stdNormal :: (MonadRandom m) => m Double
stdNormal = do
    (x,_) <- stdNormals
    return x

-- |Generate a sample from the standard normal distribution with a given
--  mean and variance.
normal :: (MonadRandom m) => Double -> Double -> m Double
normal mu sigma = do
    x <- stdNormal
    return $ mu + sigma * x
```

Comment: This is a nice way to make a normal distribution yourself, but it doesn't explain how to use distributions from `Data.Random` inside a code base written in the `Control.Monad.MonadRandom` monad, which seems to be (at least part of) the question.